# In what fluid does the sperm swim in the oviduct?

Tags: human-anatomy, sexual-reproduction

We know that after sexual intercourse, sperm enters the female body and continues to pass through the oviduct by swimming. "Swimming" implies the presence of fluid.

I want to know what that fluid is called. Also could you please tell me the color of that fluid? Is it yellow/off-white?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specifically in the [fallopian tubes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallopian_tube#Microanatomy), the fluid is called *tubal fluid*, and is produced by the innermost mucosal layer of the tubes (specifically, the [peg cells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peg_cell) in the epitelium)

- In the follicles, there is the [follicular fluid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Follicular_fluid), *liquor folliculi*.
- In the uterus, the endometrial fluid.
- In the cervix, cervical fluid.

I don't know about the color. For what it's worth, cervical fluid varies from white to yellowish, but it's transparent when it's best for spermatozoa to swim.